# Why do I get a "MySQLSyntaxErrorException:" error?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax

Syntax error, I can't seem to find it. I'm new to databases.

Error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database ( ID INTEGER NOT NULL, QUESTION varchar(100) NOT NULL, ANSWER varchar(5' at line 1
```

Code:

```
public void createTable(Connection conn) {
    try {
        String createString = "CREATE TABLE " + this.tableName + " ( "
                + "ID INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + "QUESTION varchar(100) NOT NULL, "
                + "ANSWER varchar(500) NOT NULL, " + "PRIMARY KEY (ID))";

        this.sendUpdate(conn, createString); //This part definitely works as intended
        System.out.println("Created a table called " + this.tableName);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Could not create the table");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `database` is a reserved word.  Name your table something else. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATABASE` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). Use a different name for the table